# Grails 3.1.0.RC1 how to get sessionFactory?

Tags: grails, sessionfactory, grails-3.0

I migrate a project from grails 3.0.11 to grails 3.1.0.RC1 and got the error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
... 48 common frames omitted
```

What can i do? Thanx

Comment: I made a mistake. I migrate a project from grails 2.5.3 to grails 3.1.0.RC1.
In a beginning i migrate the project to Grails 3.0.11, but a little bit later i decided to migrate to grails 3.1.0.RC1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about 3.1.X, but in 2.4.X and 3.0.11, I use something like this:

```
def grailsApplication = Holders.getGrailsApplication()
def sessionFactory = grailsApplication?.mainContext?.sessionFactory
```

This does not work in unit tests, but I don't need the session factory then.  It does work in development, production and integration tests.

Comment: Thanx! It works for me! Sorry, I can't mark the answer as useful because of my low rating.. But i thank you!

Comment: @SergeyLinnik : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work